# How to continue in case of errors when traspiling files using Babel Transpiler CLI

Tags: babeljs

I am using babel transpiler cli to recursively transpile all *.ts files in a given directory.
In case of syntax error in one of the files, the whole process stops.
How can I configure the CLI such that it will continue to transpile the rest of the files in the directory?

I am using the following command:

> npx babel <input_dir> --out-dir  --extensions .ts

Here is my babel.config.json file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins":[
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",{
      "decoratorsBeforeExport": true      
    }],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators",{
      "decoratorsBeforeExport": true
    }],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes" , {
      "deprecatedAssertSyntax": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

The process stops at the first error it sees, instead of continue and traspile the rest of the files. Is there a way to configure it?

Thanks
H Guy